# Invoke and include a separate .php from within a callback for a drupal 6 page

Tags: php, drupal

I'm new to Drupal (v6) and PHP, and I'm trying to implement some content through a custom module.  I've followed a tutorial, and figured out how to make Drupal aware of my module and even registered a URL for my custom page.  It's appearing in the navigation as I intended -- so far so good.

This is great for my toy example... but less good for the page(s) I actually intend to write.  Right now I have this:

```
function twtevents_menu() {

  $items = array();

  $items['gingerbread'] = array(
    'title' => 'Gingerbread Gallery',
    'page callback' => 'twtevents_gallery_gingerbread',
    'access arguments' => array('access twtevents content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
  );

  return $items;
}

function twtevents_gallery_gingerbread() {
  // content variable that will be returned for display
  $page_content = '';

  $page_content = '<p>'.  t("Some super-cool content") .'</p>';

  return $page_content;
}
```

But I don't want to write a large, complex page in the style of `$page_content = '<p>'.  t("Some super-cool content") .'</p>';` -- and on and on.

I want to write the actual page in a style closer to this:

```
<div class="comment<?php print ($comment->new) ? ' comment-new' : ''; print ' '. $status ?> clear-block">
  <?php print $picture ?>

  <?php if ($comment->new): ?>
    <span class="new"><?php print $new ?></span>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <h3><?php print $title ?></h3>

</div>
```

Where php code is sprinkled into HTML markup, rather than the reverse.

From within my function, I can call `include($path)` successfully, but (of course) this approach just places the output of my page in the top-left cornet of the broser... I need to send the output of the separate page as the return of my callback function.

Is there a PHP function for this?  A Drupal function?  Best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kniganapolke says, you want a hook theme implementation to call a template;

Something like;

```
function twtevents_theme(){
    return array(
        'template' => 'twtevents_gallery_gingerbread',
        'arguments' => array()
    ); }
```

Then place your template code into a file called twtevents_gallery_gingerbread.tpl.php in your module folder.

Then update your page callback to call the theme function like this;

```
function twtevents_gallery_gingerbread(){
    return theme('twtevents_gallery_gingerbread');
}
```

**Now here is the important bit - once you've added the theme hook to your module you must clear your Drupal cache, otherwise it won't find your new template.**

Comment: Thanks!  Both answers were very helpful... wish I could "accept" both.  As a PHP/Drupal newb, it makes a big difference that your code examples are more tailored to my situation and more complete (showing the full twtevents_gallery_gingerbread() function).

Answer (score 2):

To use your custom template file in a module, you should provide your `hook_theme` implementation. Below there is an example from [advanced forum](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) module.

```
function advanced_forum_theme() {
  // ...
  $items['advanced_forum_topic_header'] = array(
      'template' => 'advanced_forum-topic-header',
      'arguments' => array(
        'node' => NULL,
        'comment_count' => NULL,
        )
  );
  // ...
  return $items;
}
```

This is how the hook is invoked:

```
  // Build the topic header
  $variables['topic_header'] = theme('advanced_forum_topic_header',
                                      $variables['node'],
                                      $variables['comment_count']);
```

The template file that contains the layout is `advanced_forum-topic-header.tpl.php`.

Some links for more details: ["Using hook_theme to style module output"](http://groups.drupal.org/node/14274), [hook_theme description for Drupal 6](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme/6).